# One-line command for setting a WIndows Env Variable

Tags: command, wmic

I'm looking for a one-line command that can pull info from the BIOS and store it as a Machine-wide environment variable in Windows.  Something like this:

```
for /f "skip=1" %i IN ('wmic bios get serialnumber') DO @if not defined _A @echo %i&set _A=1) &set BIOSTag=%i
```

I've made this work once, but it only stores it as a temporary variable, not machine-wide and certainly not persistent.  The ultimate goal is to have my Answer File (or Unattend File) use this command during the Specialize Pass to pull either the SerialNumber or IdentificationCode (which I believe is the AssetTag you can manually specify) from the BIOS and store it as a permanent environment variable, followed by the "amd64_Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup_neutral" component specifying the ComputerName as: "%BIOSTag%-string".

This should work, in theory, as I'm currently able to use: %Date% in a similar way to modify the PC's "Description" field on the System menu to reflect the date I image the machines.

As shown above, my command so far is pretty dirty, but it works as a temporary variable.  If I try to substitute `SetX *var* %i /M` at the end to make it a permanent environment variable the command executes but nothing seems to change, and I can't echo the variable.

Answer (score 0):

My apologies!  After several hours of testing, it seems I just forgot to clear the _A temporary variable from that command line.  The following one-liner pulls my ServiceTag from the BIOS and saves it as the %BIOSTAG% permanent machine environment variable:

```
for /f "skip=1" %i IN ('wmic bios get serialnumber') DO @if not defined _A @echo %i&set _A=1) &SETX BIOSTAG %i /M
```

She isn't pretty, but she'll do.  :-)   Now to test with an Answer File and see if I can use %BIOSTAG%-*suffix* to generate appropriately named machines!  If so we can use the customizable AssetTag field in the BIOS to name the machines whatever we like automatically.  We have to configure the BIOS manually with new machines anyway, so that's not difficult.  The only catch now will be whether or not the WMIC query for IdentificationCode pulls the AssetTag field data from a Dell BIOS...

I hope this post can help somebody in the future!